# React Redux and aggrid rebinding data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Having another issue with aggrid where I can't seem to figure out how to update a table of checkboxes the best way.

I can turn deltaRowDataMode off and all works well, however it renders the whole grid and I just don't like the idea of ignoring performance. (incase i had thousands of users).

I set deltaRowDataMode 'on' which makes the grid move/update/remove fast, I also have dynamic columns (generated through redux store and api call) and cells based off data, which is working alright... Until I try to calibrate the value of my checkboxes. For example by default it will look like this, if i have this permission 'administrator.assign.privileges'

[image]

However when I check my next box all my data will update and what not, but my checkbox won't be checked.

[image]

As you can see the data is getting passed, and checking the next state its there. However the 4th box is not checked. But when I do check another box after that, then the box before 'checks'. This leads me to believe that I am one step behind my state and I need another rendering update what is the best approach to take?

This is my cellRendererFramework component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import _ from 'lodash';

class CheckboxRenderer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: false,
        };
        this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setDefaultState();
    }

    setDefaultState() {
      const { data, colDef } = this.props;
      if (data.Roles && data.Roles.length > 0) {
        if (_.find(data.Roles, _.matchesProperty('name', colDef.headerName))) {
          this.setState({
            value: true,
          });
        }
      } else if (data.Privileges && data.Privileges.length > 0) {
        console.log(data.Privileges);
        if (_.find(data.Privileges, _.matchesProperty('name', colDef.headerName))) {
          this.setState({
            value: true,
          });
        }
      }
    }

    handleCheckboxChange(event) {
      const { data, colDef } = this.props;
      const { externalData } = this.props.api;
      const newVal = !this.state.value;
      if (newVal) {
        if (this.props.api.mode === 'Privilege') {
          this.props.api.handleAssign(data.id, colDef.id, externalData.entities.Privilege[colDef.id]);
        } else {
          this.props.api.handleAssign(data.id, colDef.id, externalData.entities.Role[colDef.id]);
        }
      } else {
        this.props.api.handleUnassign(data.id, colDef.id);
      }
        this.setState({value: newVal});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Checkbox
            checked={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
      );
    }
}

export default CheckboxRenderer;
```